# Call getUserTransactions

Tags: yodlee

I'm using the Yodlee REST API and trying to call `getUserTransactions`.

In the request [documentation](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getUserTransactions), it says that only three params are required and the rest aren't. However, it seems not to work without the extra two params.

When sending with only the following:

```
cobSessionToken
userSessionToken
searchFetchRequest.searchIdentifier.identifier
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    errorOccurred: "true"
    exceptionType: "com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException"
    referenceCode: "_ad0299a4-7445-46ae-bf29-9596974af4b6"
    message: "Invalid argument value: Search Result Range of TransactionSearchFetchRequest cannot be NULL"
}
```

It works when adding the following params

```
searchFetchRequest.searchResultRange.startNumber
searchFetchRequest.searchResultRange.endNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass on those parameters also. As those parameters will be used to paginate the transactions if those are very high in numbers.

For e.g. if the response is having

Number of hits = 1300 (From `executeUserSearchRequest` API)
then call `getUserTransactions` in loop with

1st call 
StartNumber = 1
EndNumber = 500

2nd call
StartNumber = 501
EndNumber = 1000

3rd call
StartNumber = 1001
EndNumber = 1300

Meanwhile we'll get that corrected over the portal that those fields are mandatory.